Error while configuring pallet_ethereum in substrate parachain template
I am trying to configure pallet_ethereum with my substrate parachain.
I am following along this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9KfvhoqLJ4
I implemented following commits as per instructions given in the above referred tutorial:

Install pallet_ethereum
Ethereum Genesis config
Switch to Ethereum block hashing

It gives following error:
Error Message
the trait bound `fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>: Serialize` is not satisfied
     --> /Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/runtime/src/lib.rs:681:3
      |
  681 |         fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, ...>`, which is required by `sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>>: sp_api::BlockT`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Serialize`:
                bool
                char
                isize
                i8
                i16
                i32
                i64
                i128
              and 287 others
      = note: required for `UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, ...>` to implement `MaybeSerialize`
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/target/debug/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/parachain_template_runtime-9c17df24509c0458.long-type-6576611442618062294.txt'
      = note: required for `Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, ..., ...>>` to implement `sp_api::BlockT`
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/target/debug/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/parachain_template_runtime-9c17df24509c0458.long-type-17979837607570774644.txt'



the trait bound `fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>: Serialize` is not satisfied
     --> /Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/runtime/src/lib.rs:681:3
      |
  681 |         fn initialize_block(header: &<Block as BlockT>::Header) {
      |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not implemented for `UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, ...>`, which is required by `sp_runtime::generic::Block<sp_runtime::generic::Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, fp_self_contained::UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<sp_runtime::AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, (CheckNonZeroSender<Runtime>, CheckSpecVersion<Runtime>, CheckTxVersion<Runtime>, CheckGenesis<Runtime>, CheckEra<Runtime>, CheckNonce<Runtime>, CheckWeight<Runtime>, ChargeTransactionPayment<Runtime>)>>: sp_api::BlockT`
      |
      = help: the following other types implement trait `Serialize`:
                bool
                char
                isize
                i8
                i16
                i32
                i64
                i128
              and 287 others
      = note: required for `UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, MultiSignature, ...>` to implement `MaybeSerialize`
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/target/debug/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/parachain_template_runtime-9c17df24509c0458.long-type-6576611442618062294.txt'
      = note: required for `Block<Header<u32, BlakeTwo256>, UncheckedExtrinsic<MultiAddress<AccountId32, ()>, RuntimeCall, ..., ...>>` to implement `sp_api::BlockT`
      = note: the full type name has been written to '/Users/syedkamran/blockguard/blockguard-node/target/debug/wbuild/parachain-template-runtime/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/deps/parachain_template_runtime-9c17df24509c0458.long-type-17979837607570774644.txt'

My environment:
OS: macOS Ventura Version: 13.5.2

Rust Toolchain:

 > rustup toolchain list
stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2021-10-19-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2022-09-10-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-10-10-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2023-12-13-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-2024-02-14-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin
1.74-aarch64-apple-darwin
risc0

I forked my parachain repo from the following polkador parachain template
https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/releases/tag/polkadot-v1.0.0
Link to my parachain github repo is here:
https://github.com/sayyedkamran/blockguard-node/tree/blockguard-add-evm-support
